# How to get the actual tweet after POST favorites/create with the Twitter API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, twitter, react-redux

My application provide user with the ability to like or dislike a tweet. The API end-point for the actions are [POST favorites/create](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-favorites-create) and [POST favorites/destroy](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-favorites-destroy).
Also in the documentation, there is this information "The immediately returned Tweet object may not indicate the resultant favorited status of the Tweet" which not what I want, the favorite_count is always wrong (when you like the first time, nothing happens. but the second time you dislike the favorite_count increase). I want it to return the updated tweet so that I can display real data in my application.
BTW, my application is built with React and Redux in the front-end and Nodejs in the back-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter's system is eventually consistent, and actions like these may have a delay on writing. There's no way to "force" Twitter to give current and immediately accurate counts for likes, unfortunately.

Comment: So what is the solution for such  a problem? Even if I try to manage it in the state, the data returned always in conflict with my states, and the behavior for the like button is not what is should be,

Comment: You’d probably want to re-check the favourite / like count on the Tweet after a short delay.